# How to print jpanel with graphic components

Tags: javascript, java

Here i use just print the JPanel but i need to put graphics component for drawLine method. how to use it anyone please advice me. my sample code for print JPanel here.

```
public class Sample {
JPanel component_name = new JPanel();   
public void printComponenet(){
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");
    pj.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
        public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
            if (pageNum > 0){
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            component_name.printAll(g2);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    });
    if (pj.printDialog() == false)
        return;
    try {
        pj.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
g2.drawLine(left,top,width,height);
```

Replacing ( or assigning to ) the four parameters with integer values you want to use. eg:

```
g2.drawLine(30,40,400,300);
```

Should work for most displays.

```
g2.setColor(r,g,b);
```

Before, if you want other than black.